# 301 redirect from old to new URL without querystring and?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from my old URL structure to a new one where in my case some parameters are added.

The old structure looked like www.url.com/detail/111.html which is rewritten from www.url.com?action=detail&id=111
Now the structure changed for SEO reasons, new the URL for the site mentioned above is something like www.url.com/detail/111/cat/sub.html.

Now i want to redirect from
www.url.com/detail/111.html to
www.url.com/detail/111/cat/xyz.html

or from
www.url.com/detail/112.hmtl to
www.url.com/detail/112/cat/abc.html

The last part in the new URLs is variable!

If im doing it with:
Redirect 301 /detail/112.html http://www.url.com/detail/112.cat/abc.html 
the querystring ist added to the new url. The browser shows: http://www.url.com/detail/112.cat/abc.html?action=detail&id=112

When I'm adding a ? to the new URL the ? is also shown in the browser.

QSD doesn't work because Apache 2.2 is running.

Has anyone an idea what to do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^detail/112\.html$ http://www.url.com/detail/112.cat/abc.htm? [L,NC,R]
```

Take note of `?` at the end of target URL that is used to strip off any existing query string.

Comment: Thanks for replying but unfortunately your code doesn't redirect at all. 
When I'm entering http://www.url.at/detail/112.html in the adress bar, i keep staying on that site.

I'm also not sure, where's the difference from my rewrite rule? The ? isn't cut, or is it?

Comment: Yes sure because I'm rewriting a lot of stuff. For example RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?action=$1&id=$2 [L] works fine as well as Redirect 301 /detail/186.html http://www.url.at/detail/186/cat/abc.html? but as mentioned this redirect rule shows the ? at the end of URL in the browser bar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice that the rules have to be in the very first position. Now it works as expected :) What's interesting: it works without the ? at the end of the redirected URL!